# Generate a dataset for binarization of text in images

Tags: computer-vision

I want to generate a dataset of binarized masks of scene-text images to use them to train a model. I have no previous experience in dataset synthesization especially related to font-rendering.

Can anyone provide me some links to articles/blogs/related-github-projects?

Answer (score 1):

Start with the following paper, and use it to seed a literature search using [the usual methods](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8316/351).

[Detecting Text in Natural Scenes with Stroke Width Transform](http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~cernyad2/TextCaptchaPdf/Detecting%20Text%20in%20Natural%20Scenes%20with%20Stroke%20Width%20Transform.pdf).    Boris Epshtein, Eyal Ofek, Yonatan Wexler.  CVPR 2010.